# $g \circ f = id_A$ implies $ker(g) \cong coker(f) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring (for example $\mathbb{Z}$) and $A,B$ two $R$-modules.

Futhermore we have two morphisms $A \xrightarrow{f}B$ and $B \xrightarrow{g}A$ with property $g \circ f = id_A$.

My question is how to see that $ker(g) \cong coker(f) $?

My considerations:

We have $coker(f)= B/im(f)$ by definition and since $g \circ f = id_A$ $f$ is in injection so we can identify $A$ with $im(f)$.

So $coker(f) \cong B/A$. But I don't see how to settle $ker(g) \cong B/A$. Could anybody help?

Can the argument be generalized to any abelian category?

Comment: The ahort exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to B/A\to0$ splits...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: yes, so we have $B \cong A \oplus B/A$. The question is if $g$ coincides in this case with the canonical projection $pr:A \oplus B/A \to A$?

Comment: When one has a split s.e.s. then there's a split s.e.s. the other way round.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Does it provide that there just exist some split $0 \to B/A \to B \to A \to 0$ or does it mean that the "new" spling conserves the previous maps in sense that the split is given exactly by $$0 \to B/A \to B \xrightarrow{g} A \to 0$$?

Comment: Yes, it does.${}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown:

Comment: hmmm following point doesn't persuade me: of we take into account the fact that $B \cong A \oplus B/A$ and that this isomorphism respects the ses then we would have $$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
B @>{g}  >> A    \\
@VV \cong V  @VV=V   \\
A \oplus B/A @>{pr_A}>>A ;
\end{CD}
$$. I don't see why it should hold.

Comment: Yes the diagram above is commutative. When we have a split exact sequence as above, the isomorphism $B\to A\oplus B/A$ is exactly given by $(g,p)$ (where $p:B\to B/A$ is the canonical projection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to prove the following **equality** (not merely an isomorphism): $$B=f(A)\oplus {\rm ker}(g)$$ and then the needed isomorphism is trivial, by factoring out by $f(A)$.

If you need help with this equality, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not true. The kernel of $g : B -> A$ is a subobject of B. It's also the fiber $g^{-1}(0)=f(0)$. But subobjects are not quotients unless some very special situation occurs.

Comment: This is a special situation.